# Why is the variable name "name" not allowed in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

When I try to declare a variable with the name "name" it doesn't work, it gives me an error, this one `there are errors.` with the following explanation

```
(22) wrong parameters: MOV  BL, name
(22) probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var: name
```

here is my code

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
    ; add your data here!
    pkey db "press any key...$"
    name db "myname"
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; add your code here

    MOV BL, name


    ;;;;;

    lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx

    ; wait for any key....
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

the thing is, if I try any other name for the variable it works, `namee`, `nname`, `name_`, but upper-case doesn't work, I tried searching all over the internet, but either I'm searching wrong, or I don't know what to search for.

Comment: You can try `MOV BL, BYTE PTR [name]` to get the first byte of `name`.

Comment: @zx485 : In MASM(incl TASM/EMU8086 etc) the [] are implied in the absence of the `offset` keyword. so `name` is actually `[name]`. MASM can infer the size from the destination register (and it also matched the `DB` definition of `name`). The end result is that  `MOV BL, name`, `MOV BL, [name]` and `MOV BL, BYTE PTR [name]` are all the same. for sake of readability I'd use `[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NAME` is the name of a *MASM* directive and is considered a reserved word. Using reserved words as variable names will cause problems. the `NAME` directive in particular doesn't do anything useful as the documentation suggests *MASM* simply ignores it. From the [*MASM* manual](https://manualzz.com/doc/41981108/masm-programmer-s-reference):

> ```
> NAME modulename
> ```
>
> Ignored.

In *EMU8086* there isn't any real way around this except to rename the `name` variable to something else.

In *MASM* 5.x+ you may be able to work around this problem by using the `OPTION` directive this way:

```
OPTION NOKEYWORD:<NAME>
```

`OPTION NOKEYWORD` is defined this way in the *MASM* manual:

> MASM reserved words are not case sensitive except for predefined
>   symbols (see “Predefined Symbols,” later in this chapter).
>
> The assembler generates an error if you use a reserved word as a variable,
>   code label, or other identifier within your source code. However, if
>   you need to use a reserved word for another purpose, the OPTION
>   NOKEYWORD directive can selectively disable a word’s status as a
>   reserved word.
>
> For example, to remove the STR instruction, the MASK
>   operator, and the NAME directive from the set of words MASM recognizes
>   as reserved, use this statement in the code segment of your program
>   before the first reference to STR, MASK, or NAME:
>
> ```
> OPTION NOKEYWORD:<STR MASK NAME>
> ```